# Does Google use keyword stemming for ad selection?

Tags: google, keywords, advertising

Keyword stemming is the process of finding keyword variations (plurals, synonyms, related concepts, etc.). We know that Google scans HTML body content to find which ad to display.

In the process of extracting keywords to match corresponding ads, does Google perform stemming of these keywords to select ads for display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When advertisers choose "broad match" on the keywords they bid on, Google does much more than stemming.  In that case it also shows the ad on synonyms and related concepts.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it does

- When a ad is displayed, you can see that the ad copy has certain sections of the ad in bold (these are keywords and their variations)